# Removing points that are occluded after perspective projection

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, geometry, point-clouds

I have a point cloud (`.ply`) and a projection matrix,
I've rendered the view from the first camera using the projection matrix and got this result: (python & opencv)

[image]

This is the original view:

[image]

**Question:** How can I render only the points that are seen from the particular viewpoint of the camera, in order not to see the occluded points?

I thought about converting it to a mesh w/ some surface reconstruction algorithm, and working with the mesh, like generating an occlusion map. Any ideas?

Comment: do you know the object surface (e.g. polygon surface)? If not: You'll have to reconstruct the surface, otherwise you cant know which points are visible. If you have the surfaces you can use depth-buffering (see opengl for example) or use "painters" algorithm: Draw vertices and surfaces first that are further away from the camera. You can use a binary space partitioning to do this efficiently.

Comment: @Micka Looks like Open3d has a great tool to remove hidden points

Answer (score 2):

1. **Implicit Surface Octrees** ([https://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~rhushabh/publications/icvgip10/icvgip10.pdf](https://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/%7Erhushabh/publications/icvgip10/icvgip10.pdf)) can be used to reconstruct the surface and visualize point clouds. Recent advances in real-time point cloud rendering have been achieved with this method. An overview of developments in this area can be found in this article - https://trepo.tuni.fi/bitstream/handle/10024/117953/KiviPetrus.pdf?sequence=2&isAllowed=y. In it, you can also find other approaches to solving this problem.
   After building the octree, you get the ability to drop non-rendered points and render the surface with texturing and shading.
2. An experimental method for drawing only points. Here I mean that you want to draw the frame once, so this method works asymptotically O (N) and in the worst case O (P * N), where P is the number of pixels on the screen (when the points are too far / close (depending from the implementation) and the rendering queue from far to near). To optimize and obtain stable asymptotics for some input data, it may be useful to sort by distance from the camera.

- Convert the coordinates of the points to 2D screen space.
- create Z-buffer
- for each point

  - if the coordinate in Z-buffer is closer to the viewer than for this point - skip (continue)
  - draw a dot on the screen
  - instead of marking one pixel in the Z-buffer, draw a circle in it (possibly with a radial gradient) with a radius depending on the distance (something like a distance * eps, where eps - you can use the angle in radians between two projection points on the screen)
- Profit!
  Fast and easy, but I've never done that, so I don't know how well it works.

Translated by Google Translate